# C# 4 dynamic keyword - how to set custom property

Tags: dynamic, c#-4.0

What should I change in the following function for it to compile and work properly?

```
private void Test()
{
    dynamic dyn;
    dyn.Prop1 = 'A';
    dyn.Prop2 = "asdfsdf";
    dyn.Prop3 = 5;
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in dyn.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(propertyInfo.Name);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx).

To see what properties there are use this (taken from MSDN):

```
dynamic employee = new ExpandoObject();
employee.Name = "John Smith";
employee.Age = 33;

foreach (var property in (IDictionary<String, Object>)employee)
{
    Console.WriteLine(property.Key + ": " + property.Value);
}
```